# Adding older DAO bean to @DataJpaTest

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I've been migrating some older Hibernate DAO code to Spring `JpaRepository`-derived classes, and everything's working fine. It occurred to me I should use my unit tests to compare results from the new repositories to results from the old DAO, but I can't get Spring to instantiate and autowire those DOA beans. I get `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` thrown.

I tried using `@SpringBootTest` and `@ComponentScan`, but neither is able to configure all beans (even though I specified classes for each). I also tried adding `@AutoConfigureTestEntityManager`, as [recommended](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8501) elsewhere, but that couldn't find an `EntityManager`.

I’d really just like to add my DAO to the `@DataJpaTest`, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: What bean is missing? Why can't you instantiate/configure it in your configuration?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do add additional component in DataJpaTest:

- @Import(YourDao.class)
- Set includeFilters on DataJpaTest annotation to include YourDao.